# Running the following linux command on windows

Tags: linux, windows, curl, cmd

I am trying to run the following Linux commands on windows. I was able to install curl.exe and run the first command of the two below, however, without the `| php` at the end of it, as adding it caused an `php is not recognized as an internal or external command` error.

Then when trying to run the second command of the two I get a host not found error.

I am new to curl and linux command line and I was wondering if someone can help me figure out how to run the second command on my windows machine?

```
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
$ php composer.phar install
```

many thanks in advance!

Comment: 1) install cygwin 2) install php 3) ??? 4) profit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> php is not recognized as an internal or external command

That error means either PHP is not installed on the Windows machine, or it is not in the PATH.

Install it if you have not already.  If you have installed it, either specify the full path to PHP in your command

> curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | C:\Install\Path\php

or ensure that the PHP directory is in the [PATH environment variable](http://geekswithblogs.net/renso/archive/2009/10/21/how-to-set-the-windows-path-in-windows-7.aspx).

Comment: +1, thanks for the reply. I have php installed on a testing server like xampp, but I guess that is not sufficent?

Comment: See my update... try using the full path to where `php.exe` is installed in your command to get it working.  You can then edit the PATH variable to include the PHP install directory if you wish to not use the full path to PHP in your command line.